# Discord Bot, Create New Public Channel in Existing Channel Category

Tags: c#, discord

I'm trying to run a command that deletes a channel and then recreates it in the same channel category, rather than in the guild (where it not in any category).

```
        public Task ExecuteCommand(BotMessageInformation botMessageInfo)
        {
            return Task.Run(
            async
            ()
            =>
            {
                ulong messageChannelId = botMessageInfo.Message.Channel.Id;
                var textChannel = botMessageInfo.Client
                                  .GetChannel(messageChannelId) as SocketTextChannel;
                string textChannelName = textChannel.Name;
                // ulong textChannelCategory = textChannel.CategoryId;
                await textChannel.DeleteAsync();
                await botMessageInfo.Client.GetGuild(botMessageInfo.GuildId)
                                           .CreateTextChannelAsync(textChannelName);
            });
        }
```

`botMessageInfo.Client` is of type `DiscordSocketClient`.

How do I create this channel in a given category? I want to use `textChannel.CategoryId`

Comment: It would be useful to note the API wrapper that you are using to do as the way to accomplish what you want would be dependent on the library implementation.

Comment: @Anu6is I don't understand what you just said.

Comment: `DSharpPlus`, `Discord.Net`, some other Discord API wrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can create a channel in a category. The function's `CreateTextChannelAsync` (including CreateAudioChannelAsync) 2nd parameter allows you to set the CategoryId.

You will need to get the ulong id for the Category which you can get from the Guild.CategoryChannels. You can then pass that id into the 2nd parameter to assign the channel that category.

```
// in using statements area
using System.Linq;

public Task ExecuteCommand(BotMessageInformation botMessageInfo)
{
    return Task.Run(
    async
    ()
    =>
    {
        ulong messageChannelId = botMessageInfo.Message.Channel.Id;
        var textChannel = botMessageInfo.Client
                          .GetChannel(messageChannelId) as SocketTextChannel;
        string textChannelName = textChannel.Name;
                // ulong textChannelCategory = textChannel.CategoryId;
                await textChannel.DeleteAsync();

        var guild = botMessageInfo.Client.GetGuild(botMessageInfo.GuildId);
        var categoryId = guild.CategoryChannels.First(c => c.Name == "Name of Category").Id;

        await guild.CreateTextChannelAsync(textChannelName, tcp => tcp.CategoryId = categoryId);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Got List of channels then checked if marked as category and checked item name. Then Passed as parent when creating new channel. using dSharp https://dsharpplus.github.io/DSharpPlus/index.html

```
foreach (var item in ctx.Guild.OrderedChannels){
if (item.IsCategory == true)
{
    catList = catList + " " + item.Name + "\n";
    if (item.Name.Contains("games"))
    {
        DiscordChannel CatToUse = item;
        var channel = await ctx.Guild.CreateTextChannelAsync(member.Username, CatToUse);
        await channel.SendMessageAsync($"Welcome to the world of Axitst Channel list \n {channelList} \n Cat List \n {catList}");
    }
}
else
{
    channelList = channelList + " " + item.Name + "\n";

}
```